# Deleting all keys from a shelve file (Automate the Boring Stuff with Python - Chapter 9 - Extending the Multi-Clipboard)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why my code does not delete all keys from my `mcbShelf` file. When I check the mcb.bak and mcb.dir files, they still have all the entries even if I use Run on `py mcb.pyw delete`. I tried it with both the `clear()` and `for key ... del` method. Any idea why the entries are not deleted?

```
# mcb.pyw - Saves and loads pieces of text to the clipboard.
# Usage: py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw list - Loads all keywords to clipboard.

import shelve, pyperclip, sys

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')

# Save clipboard content.
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()

# Delete clipboard content
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]

elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    mcbShelf.clear()

#    for key in mcbShelf.keys():
#        del mcbShelf[key]

elif len(sys.argv) == 2:

# List keywords and load content.
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])
    


mcbShelf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Delete clipboard content
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]

elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    mcbShelf.clear()
```

The second elif statement here is exactly the same as the first one, which is why it doesn't work.

Putting an extra AND condition should solve it (I tried it and it works)
So, now the code should look like this:

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete' and sys.argv[2].lower() != 'all':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete' and sys.argv[2].lower() == 'all':
    mcbShelf.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be as follows...

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete' and sys.argv[2].lower() == 'all':
    mcbShelf.clear()
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
```

Was working on same practice example...and this worked for me.